# How to mock a method which is outside the test class?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

My code:

class C:

```java
public class C{
    public int methodC(){
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

class B:

```java
public class B{
    private static C c;
    public static int methodB(){
        int b = c.methodC();
        return b;
    }
}
```

class A:

```java
public class A {
    public int methodA(){
        int a = B.methodB();
        return a;
    }
}
```

class TestA:

```java
class TestA{

    @InjectMocks
    A a;
    @Mock
    C c;
    public void testMethodA(){
        when(c.methodC()).thenReturn(5);
        int result = a.methodA();
        assertEquals(result, 5);
    }
}
```

Even I mock `c.methodC()`, the `methodC` call in `methodB` returns `null`.

How can I mock the `methodC` call?

I cannot alter the source code but to do changes only in `TestA` class
Also I cannot use `PowerMockito` too.

Comment: What mocking framework are you using?

Comment: how do you initialize C inside B? is it provided from outside via c'tor or setter or created internally?

Comment: @jnorman am using spring framework

Comment: @NirLevy C is just another class having a method c

Comment: Your code is missing some things.  In class B, the C object is not initialized and should be static.  In the test class, neither A nor C are initialized.  PowerMockito has the ability to do what you need.

Comment: `class B` doesn't compile: "_Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field c_". `class TestA` doesn't compile: "_The method methodA() from the type A is not visible_".

Comment: @jnorman i had corrected the code.

Comment: @GeroldBroser, i have updated the code. sorry for the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to make it work using your constraints:

```
    A a = new A();
    C c = Mockito.mock(C.class);
    
    @Test
    public void testMethodA(){
        try {
            Field c = B.class.getDeclaredField("c");
            c.setAccessible(true);
            c.set(null, this.c);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        Mockito.when(c.methodC()).thenReturn(5);
        int result = a.methodA();

        assertEquals(result, 5);       
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have a doubt
In `Mockito.when(c.methodC()).thenReturn(5);`
c is an object of Field, so c cannot call methodC().
But this.c is an object of C, so this.c.methodC() is possible.

Comment: @NikhilJosephPeter There are two different `c`s. `c` is an object of `Field` inside the `try` block only. Outside of it it's an object of  `C`. Rename `Field c` to `Field f` and it becomes more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

@Nikhil based on your updates on the question asked, refining my answer.

Static mocking is not possible with Mockito and as you stated you can't use PowerMock then @Jnorman's answer is good. With spring boot and the mockito to achieve this you have is to modify the spring boot starter test dependency to add new versions of Mockito as Mockito 3.4.0 supports static mocking.

***Mockito GitHub Link***

https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1013

***Modified POM***

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

***Modified Code***

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockStatic;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.withSettings;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.Invocation;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationFactory;
import org.mockito.invocation.MockHandler;

public class TestA {
  @Test
  public void testMethodA() {
    A a = new A();
    mockStatic(B.class);
    when(B.methodB()).thenReturn(5);
    int result = a.methodA();
    assertEquals(result, 5);
  }
}

class A {

  public int methodA() {
    int a = B.methodB();
    return a;
  }
}

class B {
  private static C c;
  public static int methodB() {
    int b = c.methodC();
    return b;
  }
}

class C {
  public int methodC() {
    return 1000;
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou but i cannot change the source code. i could only write code in `TestA` class. And also i have updated the code in the question

Comment: thank you but again i would like to clarify that my file is a part of a project so I cannot give the version of mockito explicitly. I have mockito version of 1.10.19

Answer (score 0):

[Mockito [3.4.0] can mock static methods!](https://asolntsev.github.io/en/2020/07/11/mockito-static-methods/)

### Dependency

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

### ATest

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockStatic;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;

public class ATest {

    A a = new A();
    MockedStatic<B> b = mockStatic( B.class );

    @Test
    public void testMethodA() {
        b.when( B::methodB ).thenReturn( 5 );
        assertEquals( a.methodA(), 5 );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but I would like to clarify that my file is a part of a project so I cannot give the version of mockito explicitly. I have mockito version of 1.10.19

Comment: @NikhilJosephPeter Then it is advantageous to mention such requirements / constraints in the question already.

Comment: yeah this was my first question so I omitted the constraint. Sorry about that

Comment: @NikhilJosephPeter NP. We were all beginners here once. :) Anyway, the answer may be useful for future visitors, too.